# How do I stop the code running the remember() function every time I use speakRemember() function?

Tags: python

I have this code for a remembering system:

```
def remember():
    speak('What do you want me to remember sir?')
    toRemember = input('What should I remember? ')
    speak('ok, i will remember: ' + toRemember)
    return toRemember


def speakRemember():
    toRemember = remember()
    speak('this is what you told mke to remember: '+toRemember)
```

whenever I trigger the speakRemember() function and it gets the data from the remember() it ends up running the remember() function. I think the error is here: `toRemember = remember()`
but I don't see why it would run the other function. If anyone knows if this is a bug or just human error please tell me!

(there are no errors)

Comment: "I don't see why it would run the other function" – The code ``toRemember = remember()`` you quoted does "run the other function" explicitly. In how far are you confused why it runs?

Comment: If you want something to remember you should consider using classes, those are designed to exactly do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment:

```py
class Remember:
    def __init__(self, to_remember=None):
        self.to_remember = to_remember
    def __call__(self):
        self.to_remember = input('What Should I remember? ')
    def __str__(self):
        return f"this is what you told me to remember: {toRemember}"
    def __repr__(self):
        retrun self.__str__
    # If you want to print response while setting a value:
     def remember_this(self):
         print('What do you want me to remember sir?')
         self()
         print(f"ok, I will remember: {self.to_remember}")



remember = Remember()
remember()
>> What Should I remember? This
print(remember.to_remember)
>>> 'This'
print(remember)
>>> this is what you told me to remember: This
remember.remember_this()
>>> What do you want me to remember sir?
>>> What Should I remember? That
>>> ok, I will remember: That
print(remember)
>>> this is what you told me to remember: That
```

If you call the instance of your class (in this case `remember`) the `__call__` function is used. You can also create different function to change class attributes.

The `__str__` and `__repr__` functions are use to make it easy to print the values in a string.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. The function remember() is being called when you write `toRemember = remember()`. The value of `toRemember` will be the return value of `remember()` function.
When you write this statement, the function gets executed and the final return value will be the value of `toRemember`

Comment: but how do I just get the data from the toRemember function into the speakRemember() function without executing the remember() function?